# print a multidimensional array using range based for loop

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a 2d array `int arr[n][n]` and here's what I tried:

```
for(int (*x)[n]:arr){
    for(int k:x){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[3]' in initialization.

It's a request to answer without using `auto` in the loop.

Comment: Show the signature of the function and declaration of `arr` too please.

Comment: declaration - `int arr[n][n]{};` , and I made `arr[n][n]` and `const int n` global as I needed them in 3 functions.

Comment: What's wrong with using `auto`? It is *designed* for this type of scenario. `for(auto &x : arr){ for(auto k : x){ ... } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was thinking of using auto after knowing what was it replacing. Now, I'll use it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid global variables and pass the array to your functions by reference instead. You should also take the inner array by reference in the range based for-loop.

```
#include <iostream>

// a function to display a 2D int array of any sizes
template<size_t N, size_t NN>
void display_2d_array(int (&arr)[N][NN]) {
    for(int (&x)[N] : arr) {   // or simply: for(auto& x : arr) {
        for (int k : x) {
            std::cout << k << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    display_2d_array(arr);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `std::cout << '\n' ;` is in the wrong place

Comment: @shoelace Moved it :-)

Answer (score 3):

`int (*x)[n]` is a array pointer. You can't assign an array to an array pointer. Simply change it to an array reference:

```
for(int (&x)[n] : arr) {
    for(int k : x) {
        std::cout << k << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I also fixed the typo in the third line.

Comment: I have not understood why we cannot assign array to array pointer, but I'll remember the rule.   Thanks Bessie

Comment: Same reason you can't assign an int to a int pointer: `int* x = 3`.

Comment: that was easy, I should have understood it myself. Thanks BessieTheCow :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
int main() {
    int arr[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for (int (&x)[3] : arr) {
        for (int k : x) {
            cout << k << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```